# Jquery Data Table - warning "Cannot reinitialize Data Table" only at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

I've placed a pair of tables inside a page, both served as server-side managed datatable objects....

one is visible and user accessed, 
the second one is hidden in an invisible frame (it's used only to generate structures used for .xls export because need to show less columns on display but need all columns to be exported).

to keep both tables aligned, 
a call to `.draw()` method of the second datatable has been inserted into .draw event handler of the first...

this is the table definition in html:

```
<table id="index_quotes" class="display" data-source="<%= quotes_url(format: 'json')%>">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><%= I18n.t('quote_ref') %></th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th><%= I18n.t('quote_date') %></th>
        <th><%= I18n.t('quote_customer') %></th>
        <th><%= I18n.t('quote_pcs') %></th>
        <th><%= I18n.t('quote_tot_amnt') %></th>
        <th><%= I18n.t('quote_net_amnt') %></th>
        <th><%= I18n.t('quote_discount') %></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    ...
    </tbody>

  </table>

  <!-- hidden div used to store datatable used for export to .xls functionalities -->
  <div style="display:none;">

      <table id="index_quotes_export" class="display" data-source="<%= quotes_url(format: 'json')%>">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><%= I18n.t('quote_ref') %></th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th><%= I18n.t('quote_date') %></th>
          <th><%= I18n.t('quote_customer') %></th>
          <th><%= I18n.t('quote_pcs') %></th>
          <th><%= I18n.t('quote_tot_amnt') %></th>
          <th><%= I18n.t('quote_net_amnt') %></th>
          <th><%= I18n.t('quote_discount') %></th>
          <th><%= I18n.t('quote_mat_group') %></th>
          <th><%= I18n.t('quote_seller') %></th>
          <th><%= I18n.t('quote_area_mgr') %></th>
          <th><%= I18n.t('quote_notes') %></th>
          <th><%= I18n.t('quote_feedback') %></th>
          <th><%= I18n.t('quote_private_notes') %></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      ....
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

this is the javascript section of the page:
(column specifications omitted to shorten code section!)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //
  // datatables initialization
  jQuery(function() {
    // main display table definition
    $("#index_quotes").dataTable({
      bJQueryUI: true,
      bAutoWidth: false,
      bLengthChange: false,
      bProcessing: true,
      bServerSide: true,
      ajax: {
        url: $('#index_quotes').data('source'),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        data: function(d) {
          var dt_params;
          $.extend(d, $('#index_quotes').data);
          dt_params = $('#index_quotes').data('dt_params');
          if (dt_params) {
            $.extend(d, dt_params);
          }
        }
      },
      iDisplayLength: 15,
      aaSorting: [[0, "asc"]],
      aoColumns: [
        ....
      ]
    }).on( 'draw.dt', function () {
      var search_filter = $('.dataTables_filter input').val();
      $('#index_quotes_export').DataTable().search(search_filter);
      $('#index_quotes_export').DataTable().draw();
    });
    // export table definition
    $("#index_quotes_export").dataTable({
      bJQueryUI: false,
      bLengthChange: false,
      bProcessing: true,
      bServerSide: true,
      iDisplayLength: -1,
      ajax: {
        url: $('#index_quotes').data('source'),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        data: function(d) {
          var dt_params;
          $.extend(d, $('#index_quotes').data);
          dt_params = $('#index_quotes').data('dt_params');
          if (dt_params) {
            $.extend(d, dt_params);
          }
        }
      },
      aoColumns: [
          ....
      ]
    });
  });
```

please note that:

- this code is inserted inside an .html.erb file (ruby on rails env!)
- no errors at all appears running code in development (all is working fine, when i operate on the main datatable, the hidden one will change exactly aligned as requested!)
- when i publish code on production env (ubuntu linux 16.04 lts + apache + phusion passenger) both datatables seems to be working fine except for the warning message presented on client browser when you load or refresh the page, if you operate inside the page itself with search, pagination or other actions all seems to be working fine!

waiting your suggestions...

regards,

francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the error is due to racing condition where `$('#index_quotes_export').DataTable().search(search_filter);` is executed faster than table definition `$("#index_quotes_export").dataTable()`.

I would attach event handler after initializing both tables.

```js
$("#index_quotes").dataTable({ /* ... skipped ... */ });
$("#index_quotes_export").dataTable({ /* ... skipped ... */ });

$("#index_quotes").on('draw.dt', function(){ /* ... skipped ... */ });
```

Your code in the draw event handler doesn't make sense to me, but since your question wasn't about that, I leave the implementation details up to you.

Comment: I'll try this today.... then update you on the results!! (just to explain, the code inside .draw() event handler is used for alignment of search filter of second table to the first one, then it forces second table to re-draw to make table contents exactly the same, only difference the second has no pagination and will return all records extracted from query, using this workaround, lets the operator see on screen search-filtered and paged results but exports all resulting items without dealing with pagination!)

Comment: modified code as you suggested, warning disappeared.... many thanks for your suggestion, I've marked your answer as solution! regards. Francesco